# Reading a raster map cells values in C#?

Tags: raster, c#, raster-conversion

Suppose I have a raster map file (TIFF, TGA, JNG... etc) loaded with geo-info manifested by the cells values.
I need to read the values of the raster map cells "programatically" in a C# program.

P.S: I don't want to use "heavy" tools or libraries (like ArcGis and ArcObjects) for such a simple task.

Comment: Almost all raster storage formats are already one of the two you mention.  Please edit your question, then, to include information about its current format. Consider also sharing your reasons why this question belongs on a GIS site--it looks more like a generic data-conversion question that might be handled better on SO once it is clarified.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the GDal bindings for C#: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrCsharpRaster. There are a couple example files in C# on that page for dealing with rasters. `gdalnumeric.LoadFile(path)` returns an array that you can use to access individual cells. But I believe that gdalnumeric is a python only library.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at SAGA GIS that can be called from the command line.  See [SAGA CMD](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/saga-gis/wiki/Executing%20Modules%20with%20SAGA%20CMD) for further details